# How do investigative traits work?

Tags: investigation, prowlers-and-paragons

I'm about to run a game of Prowlers & Paragons.

I have tried it once before, but every scenario I planned was derailed quickly because rolls do not determine success or failure, but rather who gets to narrate the outcome (which I mostly like).

This is primarily a problem when the players try to interrogate an NPC, search for leads and clues or be perceptive about something, since if the players pass the rolls they get to narrate the outcome, therefore I can't feed them information that leads the group in the directions I have planned like I would in other games.

It is worth mentioning that in the *Prowlers & Paragons Quickstart Issue*, there is a scenario in which the players can benefit from a successful perception roll and there are several details that they are somehow supposed to get if they pass. This leads me to think there is a nuance I'm missing.
Can anyone help clarify the issue?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using rolls in investigative skills to indicate success or failure like I would in any other RPG, leaving the narration rules in effect in all other rolls.
I don't know if it's the "official answer" but it worked and we had a good time. 
There is a new edition of this system coming up, I hope they will address the issue in it.